# Some properties of Lipschitz diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lipschitz-functions, diffeomorphism

Suppose I have got two bounded Lipschitz domains $A$ and $B$, both subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose I have a Lipschitz diffeomorphism $F\colon \bar A \to \bar B$. So $F$ is a Lipschitz function which is invertible and the inverse is also Lipschitz.

1. Does it follows that $F$ when restricted to  the boundary $\partial A$, is also Lipschitz diffeomorphic to $\partial B$? I.e. is $F|_{\partial A}\colon \partial A \to \partial B$ a Lipschitz diffeomorphism? If not, what is the minimum regularity I need to ensure the regularity of the diffeomorphism is also kept for the restriction? Most results I have seen are for smooth diffeomorphisms, so I can't use those.
2. We can consider the Jacobian determinant of $F$, call it $J:=\mathrm{det}(\nabla F)$. Is it true that the Jacobian determinant of $F|_{\partial A}$ is just $J|_{\partial A}$?

If anyone has a reference to some source where properties of Lipschitz diffeos are discussed in length I would be grateful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a Lipschitz diffeomorphism? What you wrote in the 1st paragraph is a bilipschitz **homeomorphism**. Your 2nd question is even less clear.

Comment: I meant what I wrote. I edited the second question.

Comment: What you wrote is inclear.

Comment: In some books it is called "Lipschitz diffeomorphism". If you prefer Bilipschitz homeomorphism, OK. Is something else unclear other than the terminology?

Comment: 1. If by a Lipschitz diffeomorphism (which book did you find this terminology in?) You indeed mean a bilipschitz homeomorphism, then how come the answer to your 1st question is not immediately obvious (positive)? Which part of the definition you could not check? 2. Nothing at all is clear in the second question. First of all, $F$ is differentiable only almost everywhere in the domain, thus $\nabla F$ might not be defined anywhere on the boundary of the domain. Next: There is no canonical definition of the Jacobian determinant of the restriction of $F$ to the boundary. How do you define it?

Comment: You claim that there's "nothing at all" "clear" in 2. yet you seem to understand it well and provide a full answer. Do you understand the meaning of the words "nothing at all is clear"?